# Verifying a proof that $\frac{x^2}{y^3}+\frac{y^2}{z^3}+\frac{z^2}{x^3}≥x^2+y^2+z^2$ when $xyz=1$ and x,y,z are positive real number

Tags: inequality, summation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

if $xyz=1$ and $x,y,z$ are positive real number

prove

$$ \frac{x^2 }{y^3}+\frac{y^2 }{z^3}+\frac{z^2 }{x^3}≥x^2+y^2+z^2$$

This is presumbly a middle school question, schoolmates put it on group chat, and we-engineering master degree students- still don't have an answer. I've spend couple of hours, can't solve it. I've tried method of Lagrange multipliers, but cat't get clear progress after setting derivatives to 0, but it may be simply  me not grasping this method. Also tried AM-GM inequality, but it seems not applicable because both side are the form of AM.

I feel it could be solved by amplification and minification, but can't think of one by myself.

First time here, please forgive my expression problems if not meeting standards of this community.

Comment: There are plenty of those under the tag AM-GM

Comment: can I have a link? sorry can't find the tag AM-GM

Comment: a. m-g. m. -inequality

Comment: Just for the record, if a question of yours gets closed, it's better to edit it and then wait for it to be reopened, rather than deleting it and reposting. But it's not a big deal.

Comment: SORRY about that, I'm new here. When I first posted  the original question, it got amended for better clarification and typing immediately by others,  after it got closed and my a couple editions, received no response, so I thought it can't be reopened. Sorry.

Comment: It takes some time to reopen the question, as the new version must be approved by 5 users with enough reputation. In your case it had already been approved by 4 users (although in your defense, I'm not sure you could have known that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{y^3}=\frac{1}{19}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{11x^2}{y^3}+\frac{7y^2}{z^3}+\frac{z^2}{x^3}\right).$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: it's great help! Sorry to know that I've tread on some rules you guys work hard to preserve, my sincere apolopy! Next time I'll be careful.